# Pandas giving me different outputs when compared to Python datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) says pandas `datetime` works with reference to `python` default `strftime`. But, It giving me different results with same dates in part of my code.

[image: format parameter in pandas]

As here it is referencing to input `format` same as `python` `strftime`.

Using `python` `strptime`

```
import datetime
date = '19981128'
date_python = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

output:

```
ValueError: time data '19981128' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

Using same with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

date = '19981128'
date_pandas = pd.to_datetime(date, errors='coerce', format='%Y/%m/%d')
print(date_pandas)
```

output

```
1998-11-28 00:00:00
```

`pandas` Documention clearly says `datetime` module in `pandas` replicates behaviour of `python` strptime. Which is not happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` has a "special fast-path for iso8601 formatted datetime strings".  [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) specifies YMD order for a date.

From pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py:

```
    if format is not None:
        # There is a special fast-path for iso8601 formatted
        # datetime strings, so in those cases don't use the inferred
        # format because this path makes process slower in this
        # special case
        format_is_iso8601 = format_is_iso(format)
        if format_is_iso8601:
            require_iso8601 = not infer_datetime_format
            format = None
```

When the provided format passes the `format_is_iso()` test the fast-path code is used and (through experimentation) allows slash, hyphen or nothing between the YMD.  You can also see below that if YMD isn't used the code will fail:

```py
import pandas as pd
print(repr(pd.to_datetime('19981106',format='%Y/%m/%d')))
print(repr(pd.to_datetime('1998/11/06',format='%Y/%m/%d')))
print(repr(pd.to_datetime('1998-11-06',format='%Y/%m/%d')))
print(repr(pd.to_datetime('11061998',format='%m/%d/%Y')))   # not using fast-path, more strict
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('1998-11-06 00:00:00')
Timestamp('1998-11-06 00:00:00')
Timestamp('1998-11-06 00:00:00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
ValueError: time data '11061998' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

I don't see a way to force an exact match of the format, unfortunately.  There is an `exact=True` argument but that is already the default.

You could always force `strptime`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['19981128','20220222'])
>>> df
          0
0  19981128
1  20220222
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df[0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d')) # now it fails
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValueError: time data '19981128' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
>>> df[0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'))
0   1998-11-28
1   2022-02-22
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Ok this is why!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ...Deafult `pandas`  internally taking `'%Y/%m/%d'` as `iso8601` & `exact = true` let me try it

Comment: @Bhargav: there's nothing to try for you. You have already used pandas and you saw it behave not as you wanted. `exact = True` is the default as Mark mentioned.

Comment: Yes @ThomasWeller...Thank you so much Thomas for your inputs.

Comment: @Bhargav `pd.to_datetime('19981106',format='%Y/%m/%d', exact=True)` did not fail, so `exact=True` *doesn't* work.  `exact=True` is already the default.

Comment: I'm accepting @Mark answer...I'm looking for reason & solution as issue with `pandas` ...@Mark given me that

Comment: @Bhargav: check your code again. `exact = True` doesn't change anything: https://ideone.com/huenlQ You must have modified something else.

Comment: @Bhargav I updated with a solution that does work, but its slower if you have a large database to convert.

Comment: Ohh I'm printing wrong variable..It's 4Am thiking about this issue...Thanks for noticing @Thomas you saved me again!

Comment: Ok, Using `lambda` & verifying formats also works...

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> Returns
>
> datetime
>
> If parsing succeeded. Return type depends on input (**types in parenthesis correspond to fallback** in case of unsuccessful timezone or out-of-range timestamp parsing):
>
> scalar: Timestamp (or datetime.datetime)

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

and

> Notes
>
> Many input types are supported, and lead to different output types:
>
> scalars can be int, float, str, datetime object (from stdlib datetime module or numpy). **They are converted to Timestamp when possible**, otherwise they are converted to datetime.datetime.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

and

> The following causes are responsible for datetime.datetime objects being returned [...]

None of the reasons listed there apply to your case.

Your date can be converted into a timestamp, so datetime is not used.

```py
print(pd.Timestamp(date))
```

Output:

```
1998-11-28 00:00:00
```

You can parse with `strptime` first and pass the result to Pandas, if you like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
 
date = '19981128'
try:
    date_python = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d')
    date_pandas = pd.to_datetime(date_python, errors='coerce')
except ValueError:
    date_pandas = pd.NaT
print(date_pandas)
```

Comment: Make sense `@Thomas`  ...I've Just updated the question with screenshot...I'm worried about `formating`...As you can see the issue with formmating the reference link provided clearly redirecting to `python` `striptime` saying `pandas` following same format as `python` `datetime`

Comment: @Bhargav: yes, I saw that. My answer still stands. I have 3 references which say that this is only used in the fallback case.

Comment: Ok, In any case we can stop `pandas` doing this...Like any argumnets available such that it strictly follows input format.

Comment: It's throws a error at `line4` as we can see input format not matches with `date string` ..Python `datetime` kicks error.

Comment: @Bhargav: ah, I see, you want NaT if the time is not exactly the format. Updated the code.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I will get same results with both `pandas` and `Python datetime`. This is because My project useses half of the part with `pandas date formatting` and some part with `python datetime` . Pandas giving accepting & manupulating date formats even though input format not matches...I just want to stop it.

Comment: Well, datetime throws a ValueError. The code from before also threw a ValueError. Now it gives NaT - whatever you like more. Since you specified `errors='coerce'` I assumed you wanted NaT, but I can revert to the previous revision.

Comment: This also works..but, I need to add seperate logic with `pandas`...before passing date string to `pandas` I've to verify with `python datetime`